# Javascript trim value before a specific character

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this.

```
var = "d:\\SJ\\filestore\\JMS\\Content\\input.cxml"
```

I need to trim the string before last `\\` and get `input.cxml`

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: `str.split('\\').pop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```
var x = "d:\\SJ\\filestore\\JMS\\Content\\input.cxml";
var res = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
console.log(res); //"input.cxml"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()`

```
var a = "d:\\SJ\\filestore\\JMS\\Content\\input.cxml";
var result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1 );
console.log(result); // input.cxml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = "d:\\SJ\\filestore\\JMS\\Content\\input.cxml";
var splitString = path.split('\\');
var fileName = splitString[splitString.length-1];
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` for that.

`split()` used on a string splits it into an array. In your example:

```
var path = "d:\\SJ\\filestore\\JMS\\Content\\input.cxml"
var pathArray = path.split("\\"); // [ "d:", "SJ", "filestore", "JMS", "Content", "input.cxml" ]
```

To extract the last element from an array just use `.pop()`.